# How to check if a GPU is present or not without generating a warning in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

- I'm writing a code to train a model, I'm not sure if this code will be run later on a machine with or without GPU, so I am using the code down.
- My problem is that: The code is generating this warning:

  - `is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Use tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') instead.`

#### So my question is:

How to check whether if there is a GPU or not in a simple clear way, without generating warnings.

```
import os

# Check if there is valid GPU to be used
if(tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=True)):
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`list_physical_devices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/list_physical_devices) from tf.config.experimental that your very warning tells you to use.  This code works for me.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  print('GPU is available')
```